# Laravel Error: Object of class Torann\GeoIP\Location could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel

I am getting error on send Location Data To Database Using Laravel `GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31')`,

Error:

> Object of class Torann\GeoIP\Location could not be converted to string

This Is My Auth LoginController. How to Insert GeoIP Loacation data into database. Please Help me

If i remove this code  `'current_location' => GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31'),` i am no longer getting this error, every data inserted into database but i add this code i am getting this error

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Closure;
use GeoIP;
use Location;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
  {
    // Chrome, IE, Safari, Firefox, ...
          $agent = new Agent();
        $browser = $agent->browser();
        // Ubuntu, Windows, OS X, ...
         $platform = $agent->platform();


    $user->update([
        'last_signin' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
        'ip_address' => $request->getClientIp(),
        'browser_login' => $agent->browser(),
        'browser_version' => $agent->version($browser),
        'device_login' => $agent->platform(),
        'device_version' => $agent->version($platform),
         'current_location' => GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31'),
        'language' =>  $agent->languages(),
        'root' => $agent->robot(),
        'https' => $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT'),
    ]);
  }
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */



    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest',['except'=>['logout', 'userLogout', 'profile']]);
    }
     public function userLogout()
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Auth Route :

```
//User Auth Route Function
Auth::routes();
```

Comment: Does it work if you change \ to \\

Answer (score 0):

This is happending because `GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31')` returns an instance of `Torann\GeoIP\Location` and you are trying to save it as a String.

Checking the documentation of this object it has this shape:

```
\Torann\GeoIP\Location {

    #attributes:array [
        'ip'           => '232.223.11.11',
        'iso_code'     => 'US',
        'country'      => 'United States',
        'city'         => 'New Haven',
        'state'        => 'CT',
        'state_name'   => 'Connecticut',
        'postal_code'  => '06510',
        'lat'          => 41.28,
        'lon'          => -72.88,
        'timezone'     => 'America/New_York',
        'continent'    => 'NA',
        'currency'     => 'USD',
        'default'      => false,
    ]
}
```

You have to choose a way to represent this location as a String, a possible way can be to save the latitude and the longitude separately.

If you need to use only one column at the DB, you can check some GeoHashing implementations [skthon/geogash](https://github.com/skthon/geohash).

Comment: Please Suggest Me any code who store complete array String into database

Comment: It depends on what you need to do later with the location, once saved, what you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to retrieve whole data on website On Auth user-> Session page like GitHub Session Setting

Comment: Then you have two options: Save it using the geohash, https://github.com/lvht/geohash and then retrieve it again when you need to use it. Or create a new location table, and save it with a relation: User hasOne Location. The option that @Rezrazi is suggesting is also a good aproach.

Answer (score 0):

You Might be trying to use getLocation method from wrong instance.

1.) Try as below way :

"use Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPFacade as GeoIP"
$location = GeoIP::getLocation();

2.) Or try as Geoip package documentation suggest here (http://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip/doc/methods.html)
from this instance `\Torann\GeoIP\GeoIP` and then use `geoip()->getLocation('27.974.399.65');`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue in the `current_location` field and how it is typed in your database. From what I read, I guess your field is defined a string, and when trying to save your record to the database, it fails since the data you're trying to save is an `Location` object.

**I would recommend changing your `current_location` column in your database to make it a `json` type.**

Then you'd be able to insert your data as:

```php
    $user->update([
        'last_signin' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
        'ip_address' => $request->getClientIp(),
        'browser_login' => $agent->browser(),
        'browser_version' => $agent->version($browser),
        'device_login' => $agent->platform(),
        'device_version' => $agent->version($platform),
        'current_location' => json_encode(GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31')->toArray()),
        'language' =>  $agent->languages(),
        'root' => $agent->robot(),
        'https' => $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT'),
    ]);
```

Comment: This Method solved the error but it doesn't store whole location data into one column, It store only empty bracket `{}`

Comment: I have updated the code above, I should've added a `->toArray()` to get all the attributes of the `Location` object

Comment: This is My code Output, Please suggest any method to insert all array into multiple column into database. Thank You    `#attributes:array [
        'ip'  => '232.223.11.11',
        'iso_code' => 'US',
        'country' => 'United States',
        'city'  => 'New Haven',
        'state'  => 'CT',
        'state_name' => 'Connecticut',
        'postal_code' => '06510',
        'lat'  => 41.28,
        'lon'  => -72.88,
        'timezone'    => 'America/New_York',
        'continent'  => 'NA',
        'currency'   => 'USD',
        'default'   => false,
    ]`

Comment: You can create columns in your database for each attribute, or you could just save it as a json object and decode it afterwards. The later is better, but if you want to make each attribute separate,you could add for example a ´country ´ column in your db and in your update method ´’country’ => GeoIP::getLocation(ip)->toArray()[‘country’]´